# ¿Como hago que se me muestre un "si" cada que se encuentre el primer módulo de cada curso?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un archivo con el siguiente problema. Existen Cursos y Módulos.

Cada curso tiene un número indefinido de módulos, lo que quiero es que se me muestre un "si" cada que se encuentre el primer módulo de cada curso.

Acá muestro lo que me hace el código que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa solo me saca de forma correcta lo del primer curso que es `"Plan de Negocios"`, pero los de los otros dos (*Prueba y Comercialización*) no lo hace de forma correcta.

Acá el código que tengo (PHP).

```
include 'database_config3.php';
$sqlModulos = "SELECT * FROM moduloscurso INNER JOIN curso 
                WHERE moduloscurso.idCurso=curso.idCurso

                ORDER BY moduloscurso.idCurso";
mysqli_select_db($conn,'bdaita');
$ret = $conn->query($sqlModulos);

$i=1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        if ($i == 1) {

            $n = $row['nombreCurso'];
            $nn = $row['nombreModulo'];

            echo $n.'<br>';
            echo $nn.'si'.'<br><br>';

        } else {

            $n = $row['nombreCurso'];
            $nn = $row['nombreModulo'];

            echo $n.'<br>';
            echo $nn.' no'.'<br><br>';
        }
        $i++;

    }
```

Espero haberme dado a entender y que me puedan ayudar. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

se puede solucionar con una variable auxiliar

ejemplo:

```
$sqlModulos = "SELECT * FROM moduloscurso INNER JOIN curso 
                WHERE moduloscurso.idCurso=curso.idCurso

                ORDER BY moduloscurso.idCurso";
mysqli_select_db($conn,'bdaita');
$ret = $conn->query($sqlModulos);

$i=1;
 $moduloAux="";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {       
        $n = $row['nombreCurso'];
        $nn = $row['nombreModulo'];    
        echo $n.'<br>';
        echo $nn.(($moduloAux!=$row['nombreCurso'])?'SI':' no').'<br><br>';

        $i++;
        $moduloAux=$row['nombreCurso'];    
    }
```

también podrías manejar con el id del modulo

```
    $moduloAux=0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {       
        $n = $row['nombreCurso'];
        $nn = $row['nombreModulo'];    
        echo $n.'<br>';
        echo $nn.(($moduloAux!=$row['idCurso'])?'SI':' no').'<br><br>';

        $i++;
        $moduloAux=$row['idCurso'];    
    }
```

Comment: Hola Amigo,gracias por responder. Probé ambas soluciones en las dos me arroja el "si" en todos los módulos. como comenté solo quiero que me muestre eso en el primer módulo de cada curso.

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta, cambie la compararción de nombreModulo por nombreCurso